# Rank elements based on their frequency in logarithmic time complexity

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Cheers, I am trying to find an algorithm/data structure I can use to rank elements by their frequency.

For example, let's say I am given 5 names and I want to rank them based on their frequency. I am given the names consecutively, and every insertion and query I  perform MUST be in O(log(n)) time, where n is the number of given names.

For example let's say I am given:

1. "foo"
2. "bar"
3. "bar"
4. "pop"
5. "foo"
6. "bar"

Then, by ranking the 1st should be "bar" (3 times), 2nd => "foo" and 3rd "pop". Keep in mind that when two or more elements have the same frequency (and the same ranking), which ever I return is correct.

I have tried using a Map (Hash), to keep the frequency in which the strings are given, for example if given "foo" I can return 3 (NOT the rank however), or even thought of using a Set (using an AVL tree) in order to arrange them by their frequency, but again I can't turn that into a Ranking data structure in logarithmic time. Any ideas ?

Comment: Insertion of anything I insert into a data structure must be O(logn), no matter which data structure I use. This is something that automatically declines many options. The linked list option is not something I can work with because when given for example, the key = 2 (so I should return what is the string with frequency = 2), I have to pass from nodes with frequency 1, so the query becomes O(n).

Comment: Assuming you are refering to my (now deleted comment), i initially read O(n)

Comment: You could maintain two avl trees, one sorted by name, one by frequency. When inserting a new name into the "names" tree, insert a new node into the "frequency tree" aswell. Frequency node holds the frequency. If the name to be inserted already exists, you increase its frequency in the frequency tree and update the frequency tree. Both name and frequency node would have to store references to each other node.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this would work exactly?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, you just maintain an avl tree with the names. the nodes store names and frequency. Additionally you somewhere store a reference to the node with the maximum frequency (or maybe just the name). For each insertion, you check if the name is already present, if it is, you just increase its frequency. For each insertion, you check if the frequency is bigger than that of the "max. frequency node" and update it accordingly.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that solves the problem of the O(logn) access to the RANK of that element, the frequency is something that I can keep easily with many ways. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't, my bad. Forgot that you need to get the actual rank.... its late..

Comment: You can use this: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree on the frequency tree. Then you'll the ranking data.

Comment: Note that rank could change by *at most 1* when adding a key. So if ranks are maintained as linked list the update could be done in O(1). Each rank node would have to maintain a circular list of elements that share the same frequency.

Comment: @tstanisl: you don't need lists at all, circular or otherwise (and I don't know what circular buys you). You can maintain an array of values (or a list of arrays) in order with a single swap and a bit of bookkeeping. You still need a hash table to find the entry, though.

Comment: Check out [order statistic trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree). These are just search trees with a count in each node giving the total number of descendants.  With the search algorithm described there,  you can look up any element and return its rank.  Though the Wikipedia algorithm doesn't show how, it's simple to implement a self-balancing order statistic tree. Then insert and lookup are both O(log n) time. Note that a variation of this data structure is implemented by `redis` servers.

Answer (score 2):

## Return rating by name.

You can do insert and query in constant time O(1). For this, you need to employ two structures *hash-map* and something that I call *doubly-linked-list*.

Hash-map contains pairs - a name and pointer to a list item/bucket with this name statistics.

Doubly-linked-list bucket stores two numbers: an integer for the number of names pointing to the lower buckets (`Rating`) and a number of repetitions for the names in it (`RepCount`).

Initialization:

Create the first bucket, put all names into the hash-map and initialize pointers with the address of the first bucket. Create another bucket with `RepCount = INFINITY` and `Rating = #names`.

OPERATIONS:

**Insert name.** Find the address of the corresponding bucket `Target`, check if the bucket `OneMore` with `OneMore.RepCount == Target.RepCount + 1` true exists. If it exists then `--OneMore.Rating`, if not then create one with `RepCount = Target.RepCount + 1` and `Rating = NextToTarget.Rating - 1`. Observe that `NextToTarget` always exists due to initialization. Repoint hash-map entry to `OneMore`.

**Query rating.** Extract appropriate pointer from the hash-map and read `Target.Rating`.

## Return name by rating (and rating by names)

You need two hash-maps and doubly-linked-list. In hash-map `names` store `name => name-in-list*`, in hash-map `ratings` store rating and a pointer to the first and the last name with this rating in the list `rating => (first, last)`. In the list store pairs `(name, rating)` in the order described below.

Initialization:

Insert all names into the list. Insert a single entry into the hash-map `(0, (list.head, list.tail))`.

OPERATIONS:

**Inset name.** Recover name list `node` using `names`. Using `ratings` find out there `node.rating` finishes and move `node` next to it increasing its rating by one. Compare new rating with the next node's rating and see if you need to update an existing rating or create a new one in `ratings`. Remove `ratings` entry in case the old rating is empty now or update it if `node` was `first` or `last`.

**Query name.** Use `ratings[..].first` or return `null` if not exists.

**Query rating.** Return `names[..].rating`.

Comment: As I understand, in the hash map you make a connection between names (strings) and the "buckets" in the linked list. However ,ifnthe query rating, to extract appropriate pointer from the hash map you will have to insert the string name, correct? But I want the queries to be based on the "rating", this is what I am given. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: @george.zrs Sorry, for this, I updated the answer.

Comment: It would help a lot if you explained how it would work with an example. For example, I firstly initialize the ratings map with 0 => "(first/last) so NULL. I get "foo", to I put it into the list and map "foo" to its node position (pointer). I retrieve the position. Now I query the ratings map, I retrieve that for the 0'th rating the last node it NULL, so "first". What do you mean, by saying "move node next to it"? Connect the two nodes so they point next/previous to each other? If I understand correctly, then again this would something that is prohibited due to O(n) insertion of the list.

Comment: @george.zrs find something in a list is O(n) but insertion is O(1). And as you now `last` you can insert *next to it* in O(1). I will try to update the answer with a picture today.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I really appreciate it =) =) =). And yes, my mistake above, I thought of a singly linked list that we could only insert at the end. Sorry for the dumb comment.